# How to open a MIB file in tkmib?

Tags: snmp

I've tried to open several MIB files in `tkmib` without success. For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tkmib
$ wget http://www.mibsearch.com/vendors/Compaq/download/CPQHLTH-MIB
$ tkmib CPQHLTH-MIB
```

Click "walk", then you should get an error message like this:

```
setting opts
getaddrinfo: CPQHLTH-MIB No address associated with hostname
error:snmp_new_session: Couldn't open SNMP session at /usr/lib/perl5/SNMP.pm line 475.
unable to create session at /usr/lib/perl5/SNMP.pm line 547.
Tk::Error: Can't call method "getnext" on unblessed reference at /usr/bin/tkmib line 506.
 main::snmpwalk at /usr/bin/tkmib line 506
 Tk callback for .frame5.button2
 Tk::__ANON__ at /usr/lib/perl5/Tk.pm line 250
 Tk::Button::butUp at /usr/lib/perl5/Tk/Button.pm line 175
 <ButtonRelease-1>
 (command bound to event)
```

As I'm completely new to SNMP and MIB files, and `man tkmib` is sparse to say the least, what do I actually need to do to be able to work with this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install snmp-mibs-downloader:

```
sudo apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
```

It install a lot of MIBS in /var/lib/mibs/ietf

Then load with *File > Load*

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

The command line argument that you gave tkmib appears to have been used as a hostname.

Run it without any command-line argument, then use File->Load a New Mib File, and choose your MIB. But you'll probably run into problems because the base MIBs aren't installed.

You'll probably want to change the hostname (it will default to "localhost") that appears about 2/3 down the screen.

You didn't mention which Ubuntu version you're using, but they don't appear to ship in any package in 12.04. In 10.04, the base MIBs are part of the `libsnmp-base` package. If you're running a version that doesn't provide the base MIBs as part of libsnmp-base, I'd suggest manually downloading the MIBs and putting them in one of these directories:

- $HOME/.snmp/mibs
- /usr/share/mibs/site
- /usr/share/snmp/mibs
- /usr/share/mibs/iana
- /usr/share/mibs/ietf
- /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp

since those directories are (apparently) used as the search path by tkmib (and other software).

Answer (score 0):

The `tkmib` package appears to have been 'broken' for some time now.

Take a look at the very old bug [No values from OIDs with tkmib](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=587828) on the Debian mailing list from 2010. The default `net-snmp` version that shipped with Ubuntu has been 5.4.3 and does work as expected with other SNMP-dependant applications (e.g. Cacti) but not with `tkmib`.

I recently compiled a new version of `net-snmp` (version 5.7.2) following [these instructions](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Net-Snmp_on_Ubuntu) and was able to get some minimal use out of `tkmib`.

After compilation, I was able to get some values returned by `tkmib`. However the application interface does not act as one might expect. That is, when issuing a `get` query on a MIB instance(say querying the sysDesc MIB, for example), tkmib returns a value of `NOSUCHINSTANCE`. However, while issuing a `getnext` query upon the same instance returns the actual expected value.

I highly recommend using another MIB browser, such as [snmpb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpb/). The functionality and interface of SnmpB are far superior for obtaining accurate SNMP values, in my opinion, compared to tkmib.

[image]

The MIB browsing, polling, as well as setting MIBS is far less painful than using tkmib

If you are set on using `tkmib`, keep in mind that you will also need to manually create a `~/.snmp` directory to save any of your changed values between sessions.

If you are interested in taking snmpb for a spin, you can download the .deb file [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpb/), and install it with `sudo dpkg -i snmpb_0.8_i386.deb`

Best of luck.