# Enable SNMP on Ubuntu 12.04 to communicate with Windows Server

Tags: 12.04, snmp

I have the newest release of Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows Server 2008 R2. On the Windows Server I have a device management agent which keeps track of all the devices in the local area network as well as any information of these devices and alerts sent from these devices. I am trying to enable and setup SNMP on the Ubuntu desktop. It is a virtual machine in Virtual Box. 
I know on a Windows 7 desktop you need to set it up so that it accepts SNMP packets from the Windows Server as well as set up a community name (i.e. private/public) with a trap destination of the Windows Server.
How do I go about this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Here is a partial answer to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/222823/how-to-get-or-configure-ip-mib-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1 It doesn't discuss setting up SNMP trap destinations.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't have built-in SNMP support, but it's very easy to add by installing the snmpd package, and then configuring it properly.

Other than `sudo apt-get install snmpd`, the configuration part may be better explained here:

http://andrewpakpahan.blogspot.ca/2012/09/how-to-enable-snmp-monitoring-on-ubuntu.html

Once snmpd is installed, `man snmpd` may give you further pointers.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already tried this link along with others. No luck.

Comment: OK, it would have been good to indicate this in your original post; I assumed you hadn't tried anything yet, but since you have, and things didn't work as expected, it would be useful to update your message with what you have tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened instead.